# Error when setting reusable header : 'Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, header, tableview

I am trying to change my code to use a reusable header and it is crashing in the viewForHeaderInSection
Here is my code:

```
class CaptionHeaderCell: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"CaptionHeaderCell", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "CaptionHeaderCell")
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "CaptionHeaderCell") as! CaptionHeaderCell


        header.contentView.backgroundColor = "c0efff".hexColor
        return header
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

The error is happening on 
let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "CaptionHeaderCell") as! CaptionHeaderCell

And the error message is: 
: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'CaptionHeaderCell''

Comment: What's the error? Which line exactly causes the error?

Comment: If there is any sort error logs please update it with the question, it would be better to analyse.

Comment: I have updated the ticket

Comment: do you have a `.xib` file named "CaptionHeaderCell.xib"?

Comment: I am using storyboard and I have a tableviewcell in my tableivew that I customized to the images above.

Comment: i think that I am registering the wrong way. I should be using self.tableView.register(CaptionHeaderCell.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "CaptionHeaderCell")

Comment: that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

register needs to change to:
self.tableView.register(CaptionHeaderCell.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "CaptionHeaderCell")